# multiple eth configuration using docker

Tags: docker

One of the servers is configured in such a way that there are multiple IP addresses ranging from 210 to 220 pointing to the same hardware.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.210  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe9b:f4c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:327973213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.211  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.212  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.213  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.214  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.215  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
...
...

eth0:9    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.219  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

eth0:10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:9B:F4:z2
          inet addr:298.8.83.220  Bcast:298.8.83.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df980000-dfa00000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:117203123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:117203123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

Is this possible with docker?
I am not sure how the application is using these addresses.

Comment: have a look at https://williamsbdev.com/posts/docker-connection-marking/